# Error when downloading a large file using data link in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

My webpage has a table containing around **10,000 rows**. I converted the html table data to JSON object using **tabletoJson** npm package. Now to write this object in a **json file and download the same**, i am doing the following.

**HTML**

```
<a id="json_gene" href="" download="tgen_json.json">
  <button id="bmss" type="button" class="btn btn-primary exscel">Download Json</button>
</a>
```

**Js**

```
$("body").on("click", "#json_gene", function () {
  var table = $('#data_table').tableToJSON();
  table = {"data": table};
  table = JSON.stringify(table)
  this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,"  + encodeURIComponent(table);
});
```

When the table has rows around 8000 rows, the json file is getting downloaded. but when it goes above 10000 rows, j**son file is failing to download** due to **lots of data getting appended in the url** itself as I think it also has a specific limit.

Please suggest alternative for this json download.

Comment: Is it really useful to the user to see 10,000 records all at once?

Comment: yes, its an editable table as well. so, its needed

Comment: Making the data editable doesn't mean it all has to be available.  Typical practice for displaying data is to show a subset, such as through paging, that allows the user to refine/find what they are looking for.  Not present them with a massive wall of text.

Comment: I understand your perspective, i tried making it as datatable, but the problem is that when pagination is there, only first few rows are getting downloaded and the rest of the rows are getting lost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) api to create virtual file links.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#json_gene", function() {
  var blobPart = [$('#data_table').tableToJSON()];
  var blob = new Blob(blobPart, {
    type: "application/octet-stream"
  });
  var urlObj = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  this.href = urlObj;
});
```

Comment: Nice! Just tested this with data containing 100.000.000 characters (97MB), it [works](https://jsfiddle.net/548janwz/)